# Matlab - why doesn't fileID variable update when importing data using for loop?

Tags: matlab, while-loop, data-import

I'm using Matlab's import data code generator to pass data to a series of commands. This works fine when I run the script and reference a single file, but if I loop through several files, my variables aren't updated as I expect. I believe I have traced the problem to 'fileID' not updating after the first iteration of the loop.

In the code below, I can confirm that 'filename' is updated with each iteration of the loop, while 'fileID' is not. Consequently, the same vector is assigned to the variable 'y' in each iteration.

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong?

```
FileList = dir('*.csv');
N = size(FileList,1);
for k = 1:N

 % get the file name:
filename = FileList(k).name;
delimiter = ',';
startRow = 2;

%% Format string for each line of text:
%   column2: double (%f)
%   column3: double (%f)
%   column4: double (%f)
%   column5: double (%f)
% For more information, see the TEXTSCAN documentation.
formatSpec = '%*s%f%f%f%f%[^\n\r]';

%% Open the text file.
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');

%% Read columns of data according to format string.
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'HeaderLines' ,startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError', false);

%% Close the text file.
fclose(fileID);

%% Allocate imported array to column variable names
O1 = dataArray{:, 1};
H1 = dataArray{:, 2};
L1 = dataArray{:, 3};
C1 = dataArray{:, 4};

%% Test filename and fileID
filename
fileID

%% Clear temporary variables
clearvars filename delimiter startRow formatSpec fileID dataArray ans;
y=C1;
figure 
plot(y);

end
```

Comment: The actual `fileID` handle (typically an integer number) is released when you execute `fclose(fileID)`. So the next time you open a file, the `fileID` used before is available and will be reused again for the new file to open, so it will always appear the same in your current code. It does not mean the same file was processed.

Comment: @Hoki - You should make that an answer.  That's exactly why it's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*FileID* is not supposed to change like you expect. *fileID* is only a file identifier, the extracted data is in *dataArray* as you scan the text with the help of *fileID*.

So that *FileID* will be usually equal to *3* if you just open the file and you closed it before open a new one. If you don't close it there will be a different number in *fileID* for each file.

Comment: To further explain the `3`, `1` is a reserved id for standard outputs to console, `2` for error outputs. The first file you open get's the id `3`, the second the id `4`.

Comment: If you have any doubts if the right file is opened, use `fopen(fileID)`, it tells you which file belongs to an ID.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, very clear, and I now understand how fileID is used.